# Cannot target body in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

For some reason, I cannot change the CSS of the body of this HTML. In index.js I have a div with class name signIn with a body in it and when I try to change it's (the body) CSS in styles.css it doesn't work. What's weird is that I have a second js file (Roulette.js) with HTML and I can change the body just fine. As well as in index.js I have an h1 that I can target just fine.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Roulette from './Roulette';



class LogIn extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="signIn">

            <body>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/signIn'>

            <h1>
               HELLO
            </h1>

UNRELATED CODE HERE

          </Route>
          <Route path="/roulette" component={Roulette}/>

          </Switch>
            </Router>


            </body>
            </div> 
        );
    }

}
ReactDOM.render(<LogIn />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Roulette.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuBar from './MenuBars'

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="roulette">
                <body>


               <MenuBar />
               <h1>TESTING</h1>
               </body>
            </div>
        )
    }       
}

export default HomePage;
```

styles.css:

```
.signIn body {
  background-image: url(img/csgoImage.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #33333D; 
}

.signIn  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: aqua;
}

.roulette body {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: have u deleted the body from index.html file?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You **cannot** have a body element inside a div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is the second most parent element of your html. So, your css selector `.signIn body` means "body inside of class signIn".
It should `.signIn, body {/* your css here */}`

```
.signIn, body {
  background-image: url(img/csgoImage.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #33333D; 
}

.signIn  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: aqua;
}

.roulette, body {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: `html` is "the most parent" element of html.

Comment: @BoltKey ok, i know. Update the description.